# CV template not compiling

Tags: errors, fontspec, libertine

I am attempting to get someone else's CV template to compile but it is not working. I am on Linux using the TeX Live packages. Unfortunately the following line is causing problems:

```
\setromanfont [Ligatures={Common}, BoldFont={Linux Libertine Bold}, ItalicFont={Linux Libertine Italic}]{Linux Libertine}
```

The specific error message says:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Linux Libertine 0" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.77 ...inux Libertine Italic}]{Linux Libertine}
```

Comment: The font Linux Libertine 0 cannot be found. This is the reason why you get this error. If you want to know more, you should provide a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: The font is missing. Install the font from [here](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=91&L=1).

Comment: Quite likely the package containing the font has not been installed. If you have some disk space left, try to install `texlive-full`. The font should be found now.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably just a typo: The font's name is `Linux Libertine O` with the letter O for OpenType and not `0` (zero).